# Check if 1 of multiple chars are in a string, return true if atleast one is

Tags: javascript, regex, string, function, string-search

So this checks wether all of the contents are inside a string, and only returns true if that is the case.

```js
function check(Entry)
{
  var contents = "abcd";
  for (var i = 0; i < Entry.length; i++)
    if (contents.indexOf(Entry.charAt(i)) < 0) return false;
  return true;
}
console.log(check("abc"));
console.log(check("abe"));
```

I need a function that checks if `atleast` one char is in a string and return true.

Comment: Use `Array.some` and `String.includes`

Comment: Do you need case insensitivity?

Answer (score 2):

Of simply modify your current function to:

```js
function hasAny(haystack, needles)
{
      for (var i = 0; i < heystack.length; i++)
          if (needles.indexOf(heystack[i])) > 0) 
              return true;
       return false;
}
```

Alternatively you could use composed regex, to give you the option of case insensitivity:

```js
    function firstMatch(stack, needles, cis = false , m) {
      return (m = stack.match((new RegExp('(['+needles+'])', cis ? 'i' : '' )))) 
        ? m.index : -1;
    }
    
    function hasAny(stack, needles, cis ) {
      return -1 != firstMatch(stack, needles, cis );
    }


    console.log(firstMatch(a,b)) // -1
    console.log(hasAny(a,b)) // false
    
    // Case Insensitive Examples...
    console.log(firstMatch(a,b, true)) // 0, which is the index of where the match is in a
    console.log(hasAny(a,b, true)) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

*function that checks if atleast one char is in a string and return true*

```js
function check(str) {
    const contents = 'abcd'.split('');

    return str.split('').some(c => contents.includes(c));
}

console.log(check('abc'));
console.log(check('afg'));
console.log(check('fgh'));
```